# Set up method for sending messages

Tags: android, eclipse, methods

I am trying to  create SMS Text Messaging using android eclipse.  I'm a beginner to android eclipse. I need help in creating a method in sending messages. i'm unable to send messages between 2 emulators. Can someone help me out with the method? Thank you!

Main:

```
package com.example.sms;

import com.example.sms.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button sendSMS;
EditText msgTxt;
EditText numTxt;
IntentFilter intentFilter;


private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    TextView inTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textMsg);
    inTxt.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("sms"));
}
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

sendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
msgTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
numTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberTxt);
sendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String myMsg = msgTxt.getText().toString();
        String theNumber = numTxt.getText().toString();

    }
});
}
protected void sendMSG(String theNumber, String myMsg) {
String SENT = "Message Sent";
String DELIVERED = "Message Delivered";

 PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
 PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

 registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
 {
 public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
 {
    switch(getResultCode())
    {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;      
    }
 }  
  }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

 registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
 {
 public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
 {
    switch(getResultCode())
    {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;  
    }
 }
 }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
 sms.sendTextMessage(theNumber, null, myMsg, sentPI, deliveredPI);
 }

 protected void onResume(){
 registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
 super.onResume();
 }
protected void onPause(){
unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
super.onPause();    
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below to send it :

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"
                    + phoneNumber)));
```

and to send between 2 emulators you can use the number that appears in the address bar :
normally it looks like this 5554 so just replace the phone number with it.

actually there are several methods to send SMS one of them is using the above which call the 
Built-in SMS application, or you can create your own, now if you want to use the above just place it in your  onClick() implementation and it will call the Built-in SMS application,

However for other methods take a look at [THIS](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/) nice and easy example

dont forget to add the below permission in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Do i have to insert this code after a specific line?

Comment: it didnt work:( Im getting errors on my codes. and i have already inserted the permission for sendind and receiving.

Comment: Is it suppose to look like this? sendSMS.setOnClickListener(startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"
                + phoneNumber)));) {

Comment: to call the  Built-in SMS application yes like this, however try to download the samples in the link above and run them, it should work perfectly

Comment: thank you. I'm using Smsmanager. will I need a certain code for creating a method?

Answer (score 0):

Send message using this

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage("1555215554", null, "message", null, null);
```

The number should be in String format. You can see the number of emulator on setting >about phone>status.

You can look at this documentation if you are confuse [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.app.PendingIntent, android.app.PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: I'm unable to search for the number of the emulator. is there any other way to get the number of the emulator?

Comment: Look at the top of emulator it says `5554` or `5556` and so on, right. The number of emulator are like this `15555215554` just add the number on top of the emulator at the of`155521`